# MS Excel not showing the x values of my data

Tags: excel

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jtZPm.jpg)

The x axis on the table is not showing the x-values I in my data.
I want the corresponding date for each point directly below it.

Excel (2007) has just added random dates.

Any idea how I can get the correct dates to be shown?

Comment: try making the chart wider

Comment: tried but doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under your chart tools, go "Layout -> Data Labels" and choose the one you're happy with. The option's right up there with your chart title, Axis, Legend options etc.

[image]

{sorry, just added a picture of the first thing open on my computer}

Enjoy...

Comment: i wanted it below the horizontal axis, but thanks, this will also do.

Comment: Ah ok, no worries, just use the "Data Table" tab then instead of "Data Labels". That will display the values under the horiz axis